# Load second drop down menu based on selection of first drop down

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

The agenda is to populate second dropdown menu based on first down menu selection. I have coded it to a mere extent but it seems I'm missing some piece somewhere. 
Thanks in advance.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label >Category</label>
    <select id="disabledSelect" class="form-control" name="product_category" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
        <option active>Select a Category</option>
        <?php
        load_category_dropdown();
        ?>                      
    </select>            
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label >Category</label>
    <select id="sub" class="form-control" name="sub" >
      <option active>Select a Category</option>                     
    </select>            
</div>
```

AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxfunction(parent)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php?parent=' + parent;
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sub").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

process.php code:

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php");  
$x=$_GET['parent'];
$get_cat="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $x";
$run_cat=mysqli_query($con,$get_cat);
echo "<option value='1'>Hello</option>";
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat))
{       
    echo "<option value='$data['cat_id']'>$data['cat_tittle']</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are having?

Comment: ERROR: Second drop down menu is displaying NO results.

Comment: when is `ajaxfunction(parent)` called?

Comment: <select id="disabledSelect" class="form-control" name="product_category" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">

Comment: On first drop down menu change

Comment: Try to be more specific, and check where it is failing. Is in process.php? Is the AJAX request receiving a response with all data?

Comment: run through your process.php and test if it working first?

Comment: 'cat_tittle', is this a typo error? You wanted 'cat_title' instead?

Comment: syntax error: `+ parent;`. there is a semi-colon, replace with comma

Comment: Try to use the code like, echo "<option value='".$data['cat_id']."'>".$data['cat_tittle']."</option>";

Comment: PHP Syntax Error: wrap `$data['cat_id']` like `{$data['cat_id']}`

Comment: " + parent;. there is a semi-colon, replace with comma " was the error

Comment: @AbhiK if those were your issues, accept the answer to close the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Syntax Errors:

1. Javascript Syntax Error: `+ parent;` there is a semi-colon, replace with comma
2. PHP Syntax Error: wrap `$data['cat_id']` like `{$data['cat_id']}`